# Есть ли плагин который может слать инфу с кастомной формы в админку wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть ли плагин который может слать инфу с кастомной формы(ФОРМА СВОЯ) в админку (wordpress), чтобы там светились все заявки и был график посещения и т.д?

Comment: Напишите сами или попробуйте https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-to-email/#description

Comment: Вы можете использовать плагин contact Form  и плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-database/

Comment: Если "своя форма", то это её задача. Откуда какому-то стороннему лпагину знать что в ней сделано? А вот если использовать правильные решения для "форм" - плагины из оф каталога, то всё можно сделать без проблем.

Comment: Ваша форма сейчас уже отправляет данные в какой-то обработчик, верно? Допишите этот обработчик так, чтобы он заодно добавлял записи в базу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берите плагины Contact Forms 7 и Contact Form 7 Database Addon – CFDB7.

Первым соберите вашу форму, вторым сохраните отправку формы в базу данных с удобным GUI в админке WordPress.

Оба плагина доступны в официальном каталоге плагинов WordPress.

Comment: Вместо Contact Form 7 Database Addon есть ещё более простое решение в виде плагина Flamingo, который также все заполненные формы в админке сайта сохраняет.